# AutoIt: Run next command after finishing the previous one

Tags: autoit

I'm currently writing a macro that performs a series of control sends and control clicks.
They must be done in the exact order.

At first I didn't have any sleep statements, so the script would just go through each command regardless whether the previous has finished or not (ie: click SUBMIT before finish sending the input string)

So I thought maybe I'll just put some sleep statements, but then I have to figure out how best to optimize it, AND I have to consider whether others' computers' speeds because a slow computer would need to have longer delays between commands. That would be impossible to optimize for everyone.

I was hoping there was a way to force each line to be run only after the previous has finished?

EDIT: To be more specific, I want the controlsend command to finish executing before I click the buttons.

Comment: Can you set environment variables that can be read when the sleep function wakes, so you can check where the last operation left off?

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I don't know how that would work, but would I be able to set that in the script itself so that end-users will not have to worry about it? I am actually trying to avoid using the sleep function and simply let the script decide how to handle itself.

Comment: Well, the issue is the controlsend part. I just need to make sure I have finished entering the string before the submit button goes off.

Comment: If you need to control steps in a process, you need a way to register progress per step. [Environmental variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) are one way of localizing that kind of data specific to a local process.

Comment: I've been thinking of "how can I ask whether it has finished its job or not" and will look into return values. I probably wouldn't have to do something as complicated as you suggest.

Comment: Env var's are not complicated, if you need them. You need a way to step your code through the paces, env vars may be the way to go, but really, you just need what works.

Comment: In AutoIt each line of code runs after the other one has finished. The problem that you are experiencing is that sending a windows message (for example BM_CLICK for a button click) which is done by AutoIt happens a lot faster than another application (often) handles the message. What you really want is a way to detect whether or not the application has handled the request. You can do this by, for example in a browser, looking at the status bar on the bottom. Or check for changes in the Window title or check for changes in pixels. If no info is available, then Sleep is the only alternative.

Comment: For your specific case, just do a ControlRead on the control and check if it contains the text that you wanted to send. I guess that might work.

Comment: Show us some code and maybe we can help more.

Comment: @Manadar that's a good idea. I had begun using controlread to check whether particular strings are what I want before I continue and didn't think about using it in this situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ControlSend, use ControlSetText. This is immediate (like GuiEdit).

Answer (score 1):

My solution: use functions from the user-defined library "GuiEdit" to directly set the value of the textbox. It appears to be immediate, thus allowing me to avoid having to wait for the keystrokes to be sent.